# Change delimiter on keyevent

Tags: vorpal.js

When setting the delimiter via `vorpal.delimiter('foo')`, it does not update immediately, but waits until a command was submitted.

I'd like to update the delimiter on receiving a keypress event. Is there any way to force the visual change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, `vorpal.ui.delimiter` will induce a temporary change in the delimiter. For a permanent change that redraws right away, do this:

```
vorpal.delimiter('foo');
vorpal.ui.refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

The vorpal wiki went up since I asked this, and it included some additional documentation.

What I needed was [vorpal.ui.delimiter](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/API-|-vorpal.ui#uidelimitertext) rather than [vorpal.delimiter](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/API-|-vorpal#delimiterstring).

Working code:

`vorpal.ui.delimiter('foo');`

Comment: One note: this is going to change the delimiter for the duration of a command, and on the next prompt it will reset to the last delimiter set by `vorpal.delimiter()`